# writing files to Common Application Data folder denied

Tags: c#, .net, permissions

i have used the follwing function to write data to user application folder

```
private void WriteToLog(string source, string method, string msg)
{

 string LogFile =Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData) + "\\test";            
 LogFile = LogFile + "\\Log.txt";
 StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(LogFile, true );
 string str = DateTime.Now.ToString() + "source=" + source + "\t Method=" + method + "\t" + msg;
sw.WriteLine(str);
sw.Flush();
sw.Close();
}
```

the above code working perfectly in administrator accounts, but failed in limited user accounts

Comment: The code would be a little cleaner if you used Path.Combine.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Limited users don't normally have write access to folders that are common to all users. Are you sure you don't mean to write to a different folder instead?

For example, you could use `Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData` (current user, roaming data) or `Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData` (current user, non-roaming data).

Comment: which folder i choose for limited user accounts

Comment: Conventionally, you would use ApplicationData for stuff that is user-specific but not necessarily limited to just that computer, and LocalApplicationData for stuff that is user-specific and also computer-specific (e.g. data that depends on the computer's installed software or installation paths).

Comment: So where would one store non-user specific data with limited access right?

Comment: @Rev1.0: You can't. It's a basic principle of Windows security that, if you are a limited user, you are only allowed to store data against yourself.

Comment: Hmm, it seems counter-intuitive that there is no location where you can save some generic application related configuration data, that is common to all users, without a hassle.

Comment: @Rev1.0: It's a security hole. If a limited user could write to a location outside his/her user area, then the potential exists for malicious code to trash your machine without first acquiring admin privileges. If you want to store data common to all users, you have two choices:
1. If the data is written once during installation, then write it during installation when you do have admin rights.
2. If the data must be updatable after installation, then put it in the database.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I just thought, it would've been useful to have something application specific like SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData but independent of the user.

Comment: I suppose you could take the sledgehammer approach: create your own directory during installation, and configure its ACL to allow write access for normal users.