# Unauthorized Access Exception writing file from .exe

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

My WPF application writes an XML file to a folder within the CommonApplicationData folder on a Windows 7/64 machine.  This works fine from Visual Studio 2010.  When running from the .EXE file, I get a System.UnauthorizedAccessException when writing the file.

Is this a problem with my initial setup of the folder?  Or is this related to the permissions of the executable file itself?  Not quite sure how to handle this one??

Paul

Comment: Have you simply tried "run as administrator".

Comment: I thought of that...but in the long-run I don't think this app needs to run as an administrator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that it is a problem with permissions to the folder.
Probably Visual Studio runs your application as an administrator and the .EXE file is executed as a normal user.

Comment: That was it.  Those folders were created months ago by someone else.  In the long-run, is it the installer's responsibility to set the permissions on folders created for this purpose?

Comment: Only the creator will have anything but read/execute permissions on that folder. There are some work-arounds, though: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/61987/Allow-write-modify-access-to-CommonApplicationData

Comment: Looks like @Killnine suggestion is to create the folder with the right permissions at runtime.  That should work for me but I may need to create that folder at install time so I'm hoping the installer can do that for me?

Comment: Yes, you can do it with an installer. [Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895002/how-to-add-folders-and-files-in-to-msi-and-how-to-access-that-added-files-in-to). Additionaly as I rembember, you can also write some code that will excecute during installation.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want to re-evaluate storing that data (XML) in that location all the time. Limited users won't be able to write to it. Sure, you can force admin privs but your users may not always have that option (and it's kinda a hack anyway).

The question below seems to outline a work-around depending on the user's priv level.

[writing files to Common Application Data folder denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475964/writing-files-to-common-application-data-folder-denied)

Comment: The app actually writes lots of different setup/config files to a 'settings' folder.  Seems I should be able to allow changes to that particular folder while requiring other folders to have higher-level protections.

Comment: Is there a way to dynamically allow writing at different security levels under program-control at the file level?

Answer (score -1):

Right click on the *.exe file and "Run as administrator".